# Get all messages text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this Angular code used to display notifications after login:

```
<div id="toast-container" class="toast-top-right toast-container">
   <div toast-component="" class="toast-success ngx-toastr ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut ng-animating" style="">
      <!----><button aria-label="Close" class="toast-close-button ng-tns-c15-20 ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="ng-tns-c15-20" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><!----><!----><!---->
      <div aria-live="polite" role="alertdialog" class="toast-message ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Default warehouse retrieved." style=""> Default warehouse retrieved. </div>
      <!---->
   </div>
   <div toast-component="" class="toast-success ngx-toastr ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut" style="opacity: 1;">
      <!----><button aria-label="Close" class="toast-close-button ng-tns-c15-19 ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="ng-tns-c15-19" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><!----><!----><!---->
      <div aria-live="polite" role="alertdialog" class="toast-message ng-star-inserted" aria-label="User is authorized to run the FootPrint Mobile Web application." style=""> User is authorized to run the FootPrint Mobile Web application. </div>
      <!---->
   </div>
   <div toast-component="" class="toast-success ngx-toastr ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut" style="opacity: 1;">
      <!----><button aria-label="Close" class="toast-close-button ng-tns-c15-18 ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="ng-tns-c15-18" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><!----><!----><!---->
      <div aria-live="polite" role="alertdialog" class="toast-message ng-star-inserted" aria-label="User session info saved successfully." style=""> User session info saved successfully. </div>
      <!---->
   </div>
   <div toast-component="" class="toast-success ngx-toastr ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut" style="opacity: 1;">
      <!----><button aria-label="Close" class="toast-close-button ng-tns-c15-17 ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="ng-tns-c15-17" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><!----><!----><!---->
      <div aria-live="polite" role="alertdialog" class="toast-message ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Login successful." style=""> Login successful. </div>
      <!---->
   </div>
</div>
```

I use this Selenium code to get the text from notifications:

```
            WebDriverWait failedLoginWebDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 7);
    
            WebElement failedLoginWebElement = failedLoginWebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='toast-container']")));
    
    
            WebElement element = failedLoginWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='toast-container']/div[1]/div"));
    
            waitUntilElementNotDisplayed(element, driver);
    
            WebElement element2 = failedLoginWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='toast-container']/div[2]/div"));
    
            waitUntilElementNotDisplayed(element2, driver);


protected void waitUntilElementNotDisplayed(final WebElement webElement, WebDriver driver) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        ExpectedCondition elementIsDisplayed = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver arg0) {
                try {
                    webElement.isDisplayed();
                    System.out.println(webElement.getText());
                    return false;
                }
                catch (NoSuchElementException e ) {
                    return true;
                }
                catch (StaleElementReferenceException f) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };
        wait.until(elementIsDisplayed);
    }
```

I get this output:

```
Login successful.
Login successful.
Login successful.
Authorized warehousees retrieved.
```

Visually I get all above messages. Do you know why I get 3 times the first message? I also get if I try

```
WebElement element2 = failedLoginWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='toast-container']/div[3]/div")); - element not found.
```

Do you know how I can get all messages text?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen weird behavior with Angular and `visibilityOfElementLocated`. I would suggest using a different xpath. `@aria-label` in stead of `@id`.

For example:

```
WebElement element2 = failedLoginWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Login successful.']"));
```

Comment: @PeterPenzov I am just saying to change the xpath and use `@aria-label` to get to the message you are looking for.